# Complex selection of data.table rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` containing a comparison between a curve representing real data `dt$real` and another curve representing a lower-bound estimate `dt$lower` of that data. The table contains:

- The date of each datapoint (`dt$date`)
- The real value on that date (`dt$real`)
- The value of the lower bound on that date (`dt$lower`)
- Whether that value is a relevant local maximum (`dt$isLocalMax`) or minimum (`dt$isLocalMin`)

The real data is very noisy, so I've used a heuristic to identify these "relevant" local maxima and minima, which is a small subset of all extrema.

I want to find the first point (per "cycle") where the estimator is underestimating the real data (i.e. where the real data is lower than estimated), but only if that datapoint comes after a local maximum.

I can trivially add an indentifier for when the estimator is underwater:

```
dt[, underwater := (real - lower < 0)
```

I can then create a run-identifer on `underwater`:

```
dt[, uwRunID := rleid(underwater)]
```

I can then group by that ID and get the first row for each group:

```
dt[dt[underwater == TRUE, .I[1], by = uwRunID]$V1]
```

However, given the real data is noisy, it may move between "underwater" and "above water" multiple times before reaching the relevant minima. In such a case, I'd only want to select the first time it went underwater and discard every other instance, but the code above would return every dip underwater.

I considered adding another run-ID for the minima:

```
dt[, minRunID := rleid(isLocalMin)]
dt[dt[underwater == TRUE, .I[1], by = minRunID]$V1]
```

This actually eliminates that problem: it only collects the first underwater datapoint before each local minimum.

However, there's still another problem: if there's at least one more underwater point after the minimum, it'll also be collected. Since I only want values on the downhill, such points shouldn't be included.

So I've also created yet another runID for the maxima. However, no matter what I try, I can't figure out how to get it to work.

So, with the following data representing a single cycle, only one row should be returned:

```
dt <- data.table(date  = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15),
                 real  = c(1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2,  5,  4,  6,  7,  5),
                 lower = c(0, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3,  4,  5,  5,  6,  4),
                 isLocalMax = c(F, F, F, T, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, T, F),
                 isLocalMin = c(F, F, F, F, F, F, F, T, F, F, F, F, F, F, F))
```

[image]

In summary, the conditions are:

- For each "local maximum to minimum" cycle in the real data (where the maxima and minima are defined by `dt$isLocalMax` and `dt$isLocalMin`), identify the first (if any) point where the real data is lower than the estimated lower bound.
- If, on the downhill path from maximum to minimum, the real data dips below the lower bound, and then rises above it, and then dips below it (repeated an arbitrary number of times), only the first row from the time it dipped below the lower bound that cycle should be considered. In the graph above, on the downhill path from the maximum at `date == 4` to the minimum at `date == 8`, the first time the real value goes underwater is at `date == 5`. It then goes back to positive at `date == 6` before going underwater again at `date == 7`. We only care about the first time it dips, so the only row which should be selected is `date == 5`.
- If there are any "underwater" segments on the uphill path from minimum to maximum, these should be ignored. In the graph above, the real value goes underwater at `date == 12`, but since that's on the uphill path from minimum to maximum, we don't care.

Therefore, the expected output in this case is:

```
#    date real lower
# 1:    5    3     4
```

Evidently, a larger dataset with more maxima and minima would return more than one row (assuming the real value ever goes underwater in any other cycles).

Comment: This is a lousy title for the question, but I can't think of anything bettter. Open to suggestioN!

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, a mistake when copying `dt` from my MWE to the post. Fixed now.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan see my edit which is more explicit regarding the conditions.

Comment: My suggestion for title: Finding first row matching condition within periods specified by logical flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I didn't misunderstand your purpose. Does this work for your data:

```
library(data.table)
# for each row, determine the row index of previous localMax
dt[, gmax := ave(seq_len(.N), cumsum(isLocalMax), FUN = function(x) x[1])]
# for each row, determine the row index of next localMin
dt[, gmin := ave(seq_len(.N), rev(cumsum(rev(isLocalMin))), FUN = function(x) x[length(x)])]
# filter rows and keep the first record for each gmax
dt[, .SD[gmin == gmin[1]], by = .(gmax)][   # these two lines locate
    gmax < gmin & real < lower][            # max to min cycle and find where real < lower
        !duplicated(gmax), .(date, real, lower)]

# results
#    date real lower
# 1:    5    3     4
```

Comment: This works like a charm, very elegant. However, why did you use `seq_len(.N)` instead of just `.I`? On my data (and in general, afaik), they behave identically.

Comment: @Wasabi, glad it helps. To be honest, I am not aware of `.I`. But as the manual says it is equal to `seq_len(nrow(x))`, it's safe and more conveninent to use `.I` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option that I think can be optimized,
though I'm not entirely sure if it can generalize.

```
first_extrema <- dt[, .(min = which.max(isLocalMin), max = which.max(isLocalMax))]

if (first_extrema$min < first_extrema$max) {
  dt[-(1:(first_extrema$min)),
     c("min_rleid", "max_rleid") := lapply(.SD, rleid),
     .SDcols = c("isLocalMin", "isLocalMax")]
} else {
  dt[, c("min_rleid", "max_rleid") := lapply(.SD, rleid),
     .SDcols = c("isLocalMin", "isLocalMax")]
}

dates_min <- dt[isLocalMin == TRUE, .(date = date[1L]), by = "min_rleid"][!is.na(min_rleid)]
dates_max <- dt[isLocalMax == TRUE, .(date = date[1L]), by = "max_rleid"][!is.na(max_rleid)]

downhill <- dates_min[dates_max, .(start = i.date, end = x.date), on = .(min_rleid == max_rleid)
                      ][!is.na(end)]

dt[, join_date := date]
under <- dt[downhill,
            .(underwater = date[which(real < lower)[1L]]),
            on = .(join_date >= start, join_date <= end),
            by = .EACHI]

ans <- dt[under, .(date, real, lower), on = .(date = underwater)]
ans
   date real lower
1:    5    3     4
```

The code until `downhill` is simply trying to find the start and end dates of a downhill period.
We first assign a pair of `rleid`s based on `isLocal*`.
These ids should be equal at the endpoints of a downhill period,
that's why we exclude some rows inside the first `if`'s branch if a local minimum appears first,
otherwise we would get uphill periods.
We then get the ids with minima/maxima and their dates (`dates_min` and `dates_max`),
and then join the tables based on said ids.
In this example, `downhill` contains:

```
   start end
1:     4   8
```

After that we use a non-equi join as a way of grouping each period
(by using `by = .EACHI`),
and we can check each group and search for the first date where `real < lower`.
If that never happens, `which(real < lower)[1L]` should return `NA`.

Finally we look for the remaining columns in `dt` based on the dates contained in `under`.

Let me know if it works for your actual data,
I'm having trouble figuring out if there are edge cases.